# Movie whose ending reveals alien-looking creatures were really humans in suits

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

A probe (which might have looked like a stuffed animal or other toy) was sent to recruit a child or children because human DNA was needed for another colony of humans on another planet?

Of course they do not seem to be humans till the very end when they lift their visors.

Comment: When and where did you watch this film? Where was it made (or in what language)? Do you remember anything else about the plot?

Comment: Some of that sounds like [The Last Mimzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Mimzy), but there is no "alien reveal" in that.

Comment: Mimzy almost has an alien reveal near the end of the film.  Those suits don't initially appear to contain humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[The Last Mimzy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0768212/)*?

[image: poster]

> The siblings Noah and Emma travel with their mother Jo from Seattle to the family cottage in Whidbey Island to spend a couple of days while their workaholic father David Wilder is working. They find a box of toys from the future in the water and bring it home, and Emma finds a stuffed rabbit called Mimzy, and stones and a weird object, but they hide their findings from their parents. Mimzy talks telepathically to Emma and the siblings develop special abilities, increasing their intelligences to the level of genius. Their father becomes very proud when Noah presents a magnificent design in the fair of science and technology, and his teacher Larry White and his mystic wife Naomi Schwartz become interested in the boy when he draws a mandala. When Noah accidentally assembles the objects and activates a powerful generator creating a blackout in the state, the FBI arrests the family trying to disclose the mystery. But Emma unravels the importance to send Mimzy back to the future.
>   <sub>[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0768212/)</sub>

Comment: How does the bio you posted cover this last piece of information *Of course they do not seem to be humans till the very end when they lift their visors.*

Comment: If it's in the film is there any part of the script or a scene you can find that show it? I've not seen the film myself. But from the blurb you provided it would seem to me that the two pieces of information aren't a match.

Comment: And the borogoves remain mimsy